# How to use reactstrap only on a component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, css

what happens, is that in the project that I am working with, there is no use of bootstrap and therefore, it is a problem when I install bootstrap to use Reactstrap. I would like the component that I am currently using, use what I require of Reactstrap and not alter my whole project, since it overrides my project styles and that is wrong.

In my component I import the following:

```
import {
  ButtonDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
```

And my view:

```
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

I would like to know how to make use of Reactstrap only for my view and component without altering the whole project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be extracting only the css from bootstrap.css that you require for that component - this will have the benefit of not bloating your site.

Copy only the css classes required and put them in your own css file - then import that.

Comment: That I just did! however, do you think you should put it in a separate css file or mix it with the main css?

Comment: I think a separate file - that way it won't interfere with other components on other pages

Comment: Perfect, I just did it and everything works perfect. Thank you!